# What is the best way in assigning foreign key when using entity framework & LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to know the best practice of creating an entity object and assigning the foreign key. Here is my scenario. I have a Product table with pid,name,unit_price etc.. I also have a Rating table with pid (foregin key),rate,votes etc... Currently i am doing the following to create the rating object:

```
var prod = entities.Product.First(p => p.product_id == pid);

        prod.Rating.Load();
        if (prod.Rating != null)
        {
            log.Info("Rating already exists!");
            // set values and Calcuate the score
        }
        else
        {
            log.Info("New Rating!!!");
            Rating rating = new Rating();
            // set values and do inital calculation
            prod.Rating = rating;
        } entities.SaveChanges();
```

Even though this works fine, I would like to know the best practice in doing these kind of assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are always going to load an entity, just do one round trip, and include it in the query that will get generated by EF.

```
    Product prod = entities
            .Product.Include("Rating")
            .First(p => p.product_id == pid);


    if (prod.Rating != null)
    {
        log.Info("Rating already exists!");
        // set values and Calcuate the score
    }
    else
    {
        log.Info("New Rating!!!");
        Rating rating = new Rating();
        // set values and do inital calculation
        prod.Rating = rating;
    } 
    entities.SaveChanges();
```